# Coalesce and To_Number in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, casting, teradata, coalesce

i have the following teradata query and it can run on teradata. But when I run it on hive, the following error appears because to_number cannot run on hive.

```
Cast(Trim(Coalesce(To_Number(Substr(JT0004LOANTEXT,927,2)),'00')) AS INTEGER)AS 
BI_LOAN_CHARACTER_CD
```

Error :

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function 
To_Number
```

What should I change from the above query and what will the query look like?

Comment: `cast('123.456' as decimal(20, 8))`? Looks like you have implicit type conversion, because `'00'` is a string. So you may use `coalesce(cast(Substr(JT0004LOANTEXT,927,2) as int), 0)`

Comment: `Substr(JT0004LOANTEXT,927,2)`, nice! System origin in the 70's?

Comment: TO_NUMBER returns NULL if the cast fail, try `Coalesce(TryCast(Substr(JT0004LOANTEXT,927,2) AS INT), 0)`

Comment: @jarlh Jesus used this system it seems...

Comment: There's a lot about this that doesn't seem to make sense (system age aside). You are substringing out a couple of bytes, converting it to a number, then coalescing it with  a string.  That's forcing an implicit cast, which is always risky, because you're letting the back end decide. Use explicit casts everywhere. Finally, hive doesn't have a to_number function. **What does your data look like, and what are you trying to do?**